# Where is the servlet jar file on JBoss 5.0.1?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, build

Hi All: I'm trying to set up my build file to be run for deployment on JBossAS 5.0.1, and I need to find the servlet jar file that I should use for the build..

All of the web pages I've looked at seem to indicate that the file is javax.servlet.jar and it should be in the C:\< install dir >\server\default\lib directory. I'm looking in this (and every other directory I can think of), but this file cannot be found.

I'm either going crazy, have a wonky jboss install, or have bad info. Would someone be able to help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file you are looking for is `JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/servlet-api.jar`.

From the JBossAS 5.0.0 [release notes](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=645033):  "Another notable change is that the majority of the libraries common to the different configurations have moved 
to a new shared location, JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/. This is so we avoid having multiple copies of the same libraries in 
the distribution."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

in Jboss 6.2 find the required jar on the path:

> /jboss-eap-6.2/modules/system/layers/base/javax/servlet/api/main/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar

Comment: @mhlester, @sach, can any of you provide a valid `<dependency>` for this redhat jar? thanks