# Why there is an error in import javax.servlet.*?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven

I am using JavaSE6 and Eclipse, there is an error in the line

```
import javax.servlet.*
```

It seems there is no jar for this import.

How to fix it? Install anything, use Eclipse EE or add some dependency in Maven?

Comment: Are you not using Eclipse IDE for JEE developers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The servlet API is not a part of the JDK, you need to add an additional dependency to your `pom.xml`.

If this is for a webapp you can add this dependency with `provided` scope and the servlet container will make these classes available to your webapp at deployment time.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

`javax.servlet.*` is part of the Servlet API (which is part of the Java EE framework). Web Application Server/Web Containers wishing to use Servlets must implement the Servlet API.

Tomcat has `servlet-api.jar` which can be found under `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` (in Tomcat 6 and higher).
Find one that's relevant to you based on the Web Application Server you're running.

Answer (score 3):

You need `servlet-api.jar`. Assuming you're using Eclipse, you'd add the jar to your build path by right-clicking the project → *Properties → Java Build Path → Add External JARs...*

If you're using [Tomcat 5.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html), the JAR is in `$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib`.

If you're using [Tomcat 6+](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), the JAR is in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

If you're using [JBoss 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731571/where-is-the-servlet-jar-file-on-jboss-5-0-1), the JAR is in`$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib`.

Answer (score 2):

`javax.servlet` is only available with Java Enterprise Edition. Either use it, or acquire the necessary JAR files (I got them with [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat? You need the `servlet-api.jar` present inside `tomcat/lib`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat 10 with jdk 11 or later version
if your tomcat server is running but you are getting error with `javax.servlet.HttpServlet` error.
Then just modify javax to `jakarta.servlet.HttpServlet`.